# if/else no está funcionando

Tags: javascript, condiciones

estoy intentando hacer un "piedra papel o tijeras" pero no logro que la elección de la computadora sea aleatoria. Me da undefined:

```
let option_cpu;


function num_aleatorio() {
    return option_cpu = parseInt(Math.random() * 3);
}



function cpu_election(option_cpu) {
    if (option_cpu === 0) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/rock.jpeg";
        console.log('dio cero');
    } else if (option_cpu === 1) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/paper.jpeg";
        console.log('dio uno');
    } else if (option_cpu === 2) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/scissors.jpeg"
        console.log('dio dos');
    }
}




btn_stone.onclick = function() {
    cpu_election(); 
}
```

Traté de no sobrcargar el codigo que copie acá de información. El boton del final anda bien, los demás eventos que tienen que ocurrir al presionarlo (que acá no los agregué para que se lea mejor) funcionan. Para probarlo en la consola, en vez de usar el boton uso directamente:

```
cpu_election();
```

y me da undefined.
Lo que sí noté es que si el último "ELSE IF" lo reemplazo por un ELSE y no le pongo condición, me devuelve "dio dos". Así que creo que el problema está por ahí, pero no logro encontrarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cpu_election` recibe como argumento un número generado en la función `num_aleatorio` pero no se lo estás enviando.

Puedes corregirlo así:

```
function num_aleatorio() {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * 3);
}

function cpu_election(option_cpu) {
    if (option_cpu === 0) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/rock.jpeg";
        console.log('dio cero');
    } else if (option_cpu === 1) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/paper.jpeg";
        console.log('dio uno');
    } else if (option_cpu === 2) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/scissors.jpeg"
        console.log('dio dos');
    }
}

btn_stone.onclick = function() {
    cpu_election(num_aleatorio()); 
}
```

Comment: sos un genio! era exactamente eso! yo lo que había probado era pasandole "option_cpu", no sabía que lo que tenía que pasar era "num_aleatorio()". Me voy a poner a analizar el por qué, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Veo que la función `cpu_election` cuando la define, recibe un argumento al que llama `option_cpu`
Cuando llama la función en el `.onclick` no se le pasa parámetro por lo que no entra a ninguna opción ya que `option_cpu` esta sin definir
Cuando le pones el else, entra al ultimo debido a que no entró en los demás condicionales

Answer (score 0):

de casualidad estás llamando a num_aleatorio() desde algún lado? En el código compartido parecería que no. Podrías hacer algo así:

```
function num_aleatorio() {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * 3);
}


function cpu_election() {
    let option_cpu = num_aleatorio();
    if (option_cpu === 0) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/rock.jpeg";
        console.log('dio cero');
    } else if (option_cpu === 1) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/paper.jpeg";
        console.log('dio uno');
    } else if (option_cpu === 2) {
        cpu_img.src = "img/scissors.jpeg"
        console.log('dio dos');
    }
}




btn_stone.onclick = function() {
    cpu_election(); 
}
```